# How to show that the set of orthogonal n x n matrices forms a group under multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am studying orthogonal matrices and I am not sure if to show if a set of orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices forms a group under multiplication. We must check each of the group axioms.

I found that the axioms are:

1. Closure
2. Associativity
3. Existence of identity matrix
4. Existence of the inverse matrix.

I edited my question, since I was able to find more information about this topic.

This group is called $O(n)$.

To check the four axioms I did:

Let $A \text{ and } B \in O(n)$, denoted as orthogonal matrices and assume that $C=AB$, then,

#### Closure :

> To prove that $C \in  O(n)$ we must prove that $C$ is a real $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix with uni-modular determinant. Since A and B are real $n \times n$ matrices, $C$ is also a real $n \times n$ matrix so,
>
> $C^TC=(AB)^T AB=B^T A^T AB = B^TB=I$

#### Associativity :

> Matrix multiplication is associative, so the law holds for $O(n)$ group elements.

I am not sure if this is enough to prove associativity.

#### Identity element :

> The $n \times n$ identity matrix $I_{n \times n}$ represents the identity element.

In this case I am not sure if this is enough to prove the identity element.

#### Inverse element :

> Let $A^{-1}$ be the inverse of $A$, then we need to prove that  $A^{-1} \in  O(n)$ since $(A^{-1})^T=(A^T)^{-1}$. We have that:
>
> $(A^{-1})^T A^{-1}=(A^T)^{-1} A ^{-1}=(AA^T)^{-1}=I^{-1}=I$

Can anyone check if what I did is correct? I also would like to know if I can prove the associativity and the identity element in a better way.

thanks

Comment: You can use the [subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test) instead of going through each axiom if you like (assuming you've already proven that the set of all $n\times n$ invertible matrices is a group under multiplication (i.e. the general linear group)).

Comment: It woud be useful to know where you got stuck.

Comment: HI, I edited my question, I am not showing my answer.

Comment: @Bye_World for this I would like to use the axioms thank you for your help.

Comment: $O(n)$ is a subgroup of all matrices, so associativity simply inherited. No proving required!

Answer (score 2):

$(U_1 U_2)^T (U_1 U_2) = I$, hence $U_1 \circ U_2$ is orthogonal.

Associativity follows from associativity of matrix multiplication.

The matrix $I$ is an identity for matrix multiplication.

$U^T U = U U^T = I$, hence $U^{-1} = U^T$ is the required inverse.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question so I could show my work. Is there any other way to prove the associativity and the Identity matrix? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'and the identity matrix'. The group operation is matrix multiplication, so I am not sure how one would show associativity other than showing associativity of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score -3):

Your doubt about the identity element is correct.

First you need to show that $I \in O(n)$ by showing that
$$I^TI=II^T=I,~~\text{since}~I^T=I.$$ 
Then
$$AI=IA=A, \forall A\in O(n).$$